# How to whitelist a url/site in privoxy?

Tags: linux, fedora, privoxy

I'm using Fedora 14 with `privoxy-3.0.16-3.fc14.i686`! These sites are blocked by Privoxy:

- http://somewhere.com/user/11111/track?page=1
- http://www.somewhere2.org/popup.asp?pid=114645006&pnr=10001&foto=1

How can I whitelist these two sites/urls? I want to be able to visit these sites without being blocked (but e.g.: still block the ads on it)

Answer (score 5):

If those pages aren't ads by themselves, they should be whitelisted/marked as not ads like you say.

I'm using Ubuntu, but the configs should be about the same on fedora. The file `/etc/privoxy/user.action` is meant for your own configurations. Locate the `{ -filter }` line and add your url below it.

I haven't tested it myself, but considering the semantics, it should work

Comment: smart idea! but it doesn't work for some reason.. :\ i tried it with the full url (not using http://) and i tried it with only the domain. no luck:\ but thank you!!

Comment: I'm working on this and it's not working for me, either. I think it depends on how it's being blocked. You may need a `{ -block }` block?

Comment: On the other hand, it's been a little while... @LanceBaynes have you figured it out yet?

Answer (score 2):

add this to your user.action:

```
{-block -filter}
<your url pattern>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that the site itself is blocking the content because it detects that Privoxy is blocking the ads, then you need to do and edit like this in your `user.action` file:

```
{ allow-ads }
.wired.com
```

In that example, Wired was not allowing me to read articles before the edit, because it detected an add blocker on mi side.

After the edit, I can read Wired just fine.